# How to refresh parent page once the child page is closed and they both are not on same server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a parent page on one server and im calling a child page as pop up window which is on another server. So once the child page is closed i wanted to refresh the parent page so i wrote one reload function in parent page and i was trying to call it from child page as:

```
opener.reload();
```

But as parent is on another server this thing is not working, is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Do your child page having different server url?

Comment: Yes parent page is on clorderdev2.uvacha.com/login.aspx and child page is button.uvacha.com/login.aspx

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792408/open-popup-and-refresh-parent-page-on-close-popup

Comment: @rink.attendant.6: These things will work when both forms reside in one server, but my both forms are on different servers

Comment: @SwatiAwasthi I've posted an answer that I just tested.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `opener.reload`

you can use `submit()`

somethig like this in ur javascript function

```
opener.document.forms[0].submit();
```

**Source Docs**

http://forums.asp.net/t/1412827.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

can you tell me how are opening a child page as pop up? if through colorbox or thickbox, then there is one onClose event on which you can write something like

```
function() 
{ 
    window.location.reload(true); 
}
```

Comment: Im using  var popupWindow = window.open("URL", 'popUpWindow', 'height=350,width=550,left=550,top=300,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')

Comment: try this way.. write a function on your parent page and from pop call a function when you closing the pop up like window.opener.parentFunction(); under this function you can write window.location.reload(true);

Comment: This is how i did, but as parent page is on another server, 'opener' thing is not working

Comment: try another thing, call the page with some querystring in it, check on client side if that querystring is present, reload the page with window.location.reload();

Answer (score 0):

Try this Javascript function in a parent page

```
 function GoTopage()
    {
     var retValue = showModalDialog ("child.aspx", "", "dialogWidth:600px; dialogHeight:300px; dialogLeft:200px;");
     if (retValue == null)
     {
     __doPostBack('', '');  /* For postback */  
     /*location.reload();  for complete reloading or refreshing*/
     }
     return false;

    }
```

Comment: @Swati Awasthi : Please see the edited answer . I have removed it.

Comment: The pop up window is coming but it seems code inside that child page is not executing

Comment: it will try to remove the cache while opening popup (Use this)                 'Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);'

Comment: In javascript console it is showing error _doPostBack is not defined

Comment: it is __doPostBack and not _doPostBack

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly a good way of doing it, but it's the only way I can think of since there is the Same Origin Policy.

```
var timer, childWindow = window.open("https://google.ca/");

function hasClosed() {
    'use strict';
    if (childWindow && childWindow.closed) {
        // stop the timer
        window.clearInterval(timer);

        // do whatever here
        console.log('The window has closed');
    }
}

// set a timer to continually check if the window has closed
timer = window.setInterval(hasClosed, 1000);
```