# Perform action after window closed

Tags: javascript

I have a JS that opens a new tab. And I want to refresh the original window but only once the opened tab is closed. How would you do it?

Here's the code I have now (which obviously doesn't work - it does the refresh immediately after opening the new window):

```
window.open( SOME_WINDOW );
window.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with something like this. Store the window handle, and use a polling timer to check the closed property of the window.

```
var childwindow = window.open(SOME_WINDOW); 
var timer = setInterval(function() {   
  if(childwindow.closed) {  
    clearInterval(timer);  
    window.location.reload();
  }  
}, 1000);
```

Another solution (even nicer) can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10792463/474535)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

I actually prefer your solution more, as I don't want the child to perform actions on parent. Makes child more modular IMO.