# How to refresh parent page after closing popup window in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, popupwindow

I have one page `list.jsp` having list of all records in table and one button at top to add new record.

I want to open `add.jsp` as a popup window. This works but when I close popup window how to update  `list.jsp` so that it shows newly added record

Here is my code what i tried...

1. list.jsp

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
   <script>
      function popupwindow(url, title, w, h) {
       var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
       var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
       popupWindow =  window.open(url, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
        return popupWindow
      } 
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <input type="button" value="Add new" id="add-btn" onclick="popupwindow('Addnew.jsp','Add new',600,400)"/>  
   <table>   
     // Here i am showing all records from database...
   </table>
   </body>
   ```
2. add.jsp

   ```
        <html>
        <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

           $("#savebtn").click(function(e) {
           $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "RecordHandler",
                       data: dataString,
                       success: function(data){ 
                           $('body').html(data);
                           $('#msg').html('New Record Added Successfully.')
                       }
                   }); 
          });

         </head>
         <body>
         <form method="POST">
         <table>              
         <tr>
          <td>Folder Number</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="folderno"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Box Number <b style="color:red">*</b></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="boxno"/></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td colspan=2>
         <input type="submit" value="Save" name="save" id="savebtn"/>
       </td>
     </tr>
      </table> 
    </form>
   ```

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792408/open-popup-and-refresh-parent-page-on-close-popup

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As from my comment from the other answer you just need to handle the `window.onunload` event and use the `window.opener` property to tell the calling page to be refreshed.

**2.add.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        //ADDED START
        window.onunload = refreshParent;
        function refreshParent() {
            window.opener.location.reload();
        }
        //ADDED END

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#savebtn").click(function(e) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "RecordHandler",
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function(data){ 
                         $('body').html(data);
                         $('#msg').html('New Record Added Successfully.');
                         window.timeout(CloseMe, 1000); <-- not sure on the syntax 
                         but have a timeout which triggers an event 
                        to close the form once a success has been handled. 
                        Probably should do something incase of an error.
                    }
                });

                return false; <-- this should stop the window from unloading. 
            });

         function CloseMe()
         {
             window.opener.location.reload();
             window.close();
         }
   </head>
```

Comment: but it does not shows 'New Record Added Successfully.' msg...how would user know that record added successfully?

Comment: witin the `click function` you have declared for the `savebtn` you could `return false`.

and then have another `function` which gets triggered within the `success` which closes the form. So then it waits for a success before closing

Comment: have updated my answer to try and demonstrate what I attempted to descibe above

Answer (score 7):

You could use `location.reload(true)` to reload the current document. The `forceGet` parameter is by default `false` and that is why you pass it in as `true` to overwrite it. Basically it is used to fetch the document from the server, instead of loading it from the cache.

EDIT1: If you are trying to reload the source window of the popup, as escaparello mentioned in the comments, you should call `window.opener.location.reload()`. Also, you could bind an event listener for when the popup unloads, as follows:

```
popupWindow.onunload = function () {
    // This informs the user that the record has been added successfully
    alert('The record has been inserted into the database!');

    window.opener.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: I think that the main problem is "how to find out that the popup was closed" rather than "how to reload page"

Comment: also anyone wanting to use location.reload() should check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405117/difference-between-window-location-href-window-location-href-and-window-location

Comment: It should be `window.opener.location.reload(true);` if you are calling it from the pop up window.