# jQuery modal window, refresh parent issues

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have a modal window and would like to refresh its parent. I am already sending a value back to the parent which works fine so using similar code I am trying to refresh the page as well.

The problem is that I am getting a message saying that reload is not a valid option.

This is the working example of sending the value back:

```
window.top.document.getElementById('txtCustomerType').value = value;
```

This is the additional code I am trying to add which does not work:

```
window.top.document.reload();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try:

```
window.parent.location.reload()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 opener.location.reload(true);
```

Some related Questions

1. [Reload parent window from child window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318006/reload-parent-window-from-child-window)
2. [Closing child pop-up and refreshing the parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139657/closing-child-pop-up-and-refreshing-parent-page)
3. [How to refresh parent page after closing popup window in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027959/how-to-refresh-parent-page-after-closing-popup-window-in-javascript)

Comment: Error: Unable to get property 'location' of undefined or null reference

Comment: use `window.opener.location.reload(true);` instead

Comment: @connersz please try window.parent.location.reload()

Comment: @ManojMevada That worked please provide it as an answer.