# Jquery select item from popup and post back to parent

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

In one of my projects, I have many different sections where I need to filter some data and select the required, for example - On newsletter page where I need to click a link to "add users" which opens up a popup window where I can search users by name, ID etc then check the checkboxes and click "Select". This adds their IDs (or maybe emails) in the hidden form on the Newsletter page.

Similarly, I need to attach a file to newsletter then I click on an another link which opens up a popup with list of files which I can search and then finally select one. I have similar other requirements in other sections of the website which means I have to write similar type of code again and again.

I won't mind duplicating code if it were to be used at one or two places. But I have more than 8-9 different sections where I have to select users, files, some other items etc so I was thinking if there was a generic plugin sort of tool which takes a url of the search page and returns the data back in a specific format to the parent opener window then I just include that code on each of these pages and just have to maintain one/two files only.

How would you handle this sort of requirement? Is there any JQuery plugin available which does similar thing?

Comment: By saying "duplicating code", which part of the code did you mean? dose 8 - 9 different sections may need 8 - 9 different server-side codes. so you just need a simple JavaScript code for opening the pop-up window and load one of the sections in it, then another JavaScript function which by calling it, it fills the hidden input in the parent form and closes the pup-up. is that all you need?

Comment: yes something like that. I have put common code in separate files at the moment so including that on all the sections it kinds of work but was wondering if there's readymade solution already there.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not aware of such code, but as @Sam Watkins suggested, you can be the one who writes this code.
It seems easy to develop, You just need a colorbox(or something like it) to load the sections in the pop-up and then a general JavaScript function which reads the selected items in the pop-up and loads them in the hidden inputs in the parent form regardles of which section is loaded in the pop-up. You just need to standardize the section object names and their data...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a plugin for this, but this Q&A looks relevant:

[Open popup and refresh parent page on close popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792408/open-popup-and-refresh-parent-page-on-close-popup)

Perhaps you can be the hero who implements such a plugin, Mr user1421214!

Comment: I have got a somesetup where I have put common code in separate files and then I add section specific code in their own files ... so it's not a plugin but a set of files. :)