# ASP.NET: How to close a aspx popup and reload the parent page?

Tags: asp.net

Clicking a button will call the below JavaScript function, which opens a aspx popup.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function btnName_onclick() {
      window.open("UpdateEmployee.aspx?empId=" + empId, 
      "UpdateEmployeeWindow", "width=800,height=450,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes");
   }
</script>
```

If the update go well, I'd like to do 2 things:

- Close the popup
- Reload the parent page

I've tried **Response.Redirect**, but I'm getting the parent page also display in the popup. Is there another way to do obtain that?

Thanks for helping

Comment: this might help : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10792482/1129995

Answer (score 0):

You could just reload parent window, popup will be closed (you've opened on button click). So do smth like this `window.location.assign("http://www.example.com")`

[W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Childs hold the parent properties, so you can try this function below

```
function reloadAndClose() {
    window.opener.location.reload();
    close();
}
```