# How can I reach an aspx page from another in code behind?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ascx

I have two web page and one user control pages in my .aspx project.

**Main.aspx**

Controls/**MiddlePage.ascx**

**FileUpload.aspx**

I click a javascript link to open a popup window (**FileUpload.aspx**) in Controls/**MiddlePage.ascx** (embedded in **Main.aspx**) for loading an image. When an image has been uploaded successfully, I want to close popup automatically and want to carry image details to **Main.aspx** page automatically. How can I do this?

Can you help me please?

Thank you.

Comment: Share the code you use to open FileUpload.aspx

Comment: <a href="javascript:NewWin=void(window.open('FileUpload.aspx','NewWin','resizable=0,status=0,menubar=0,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,directories=0,width=770,height=385,top=60,left=360'))">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the popup in the postback after the file has been successfully uploaded render the following js code that should close it

```
<body onload="window.close();">
```

If you want to return a value to the parent page, you can add an input control that can be hidden and set its value from popup before it will be closed

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function closeme()
{
    window.opener.document.getElementById("InputImageName").value="<%#ImageName%>";
    window.close();
}
</script>
...
<body onload="closeme();">
```

where InputImageName is a control on parent page

```
<input type="text" id="InputImageName" />
```

and ImageName is a server variable that you define in the code behind during upload.

UPDATE

To refresh parent window, you can use reload() or specify new url for window.opener.location. Example:

```
window.opener.location.reload();
window.opener.document.location.href = url;
```

See [Open popup and refresh parent page on close popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792408/open-popup-and-refresh-parent-page-on-close-popup)

Comment: It says: "Inaccessible due to level of protection" whether I changed class properties from Protected to Public

Comment: Actually, I managed to close popup, and carry image details to Controls/MiddlePage.ascx but I cannot refresh Main.aspx page automatically when popup closed. It shows me Controls/MiddlePage.ascx page on Main.aspx page. I just want to show Main.aspx with refreshed datas. That's it. Thanks.