# How to access parent window from child windows after following a new link

Tags: javascript, html

From a parent windows I create a pop-up windows (the child):

```
onclick=window.open('child_windows.html','popup','width=600,height=300')
```

On the child window I've got a nifty feature that will update the parent window when I close the child window:

```
window.onunload = refreshParent;
function refreshParent() {
    window.opener.location.reload();
}
```

This works good. Now I created a link (href) on the child window to a new page, which is still on the same webserver, within the same directory. It's just a new page. Let's say:

```
<a href=second_page.html>click here</a>
```

I copied the window.onunload code to this new child window, but when I close this new child window the original parent window does not refresh.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

when you open new window, current window automatically closes itself and then refreshes the parent window.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var localWondow;
   function doLoad() {
   localWondow = setTimeout("window.close()",1000);
   }

   function refreshAndClose() {
     window.opener.location.reload(true);
     window.close();
   }
</script>
<body onbeforeunload="refreshAndClose();" onLoad='doLoad()''>
```

For more info:- [Click me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792408/open-popup-and-refresh-parent-page-on-close-popup)

Comment: I clicked your link for more info, but that information is for the simple parent - child window. My question is, I have a parent window which opens a child window, from the child window I link to a new page, and when that new page is closed I want to refresh the original parent window.